# Передача контекста

Tags: javascript, замыкания

Привет!
Подскажите, пожалуйста. Есть код:

```
$(this).each(function (e) {
     var $this = $(this),
     dataTest = $this.attr('data-test');

     $this.on('click', function (event) {
        showTest(dataTest , $this);
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Здесь по клику на переменную идет показ блока.
Но этот вариант не предусматривает момент, когда dom меняется после загрузки. На ум пришла мысль использовать относительно метод `.on` , то есть:

```
$(this).each(function (e) {
         var $this = $(this),
         dataTest = $this.attr('data-test');

         $('body').on('click', $this, function (event) {
            showTest(dataTest , $this);
            event.preventDefault();
        });
    });
```

Но при таком варианте меняется контекст и `$this` ссылается на `body` .

Не могу понять как переопределить контекст. На ум приходят методы `bind` и `call` , но сообразить не получилось.

Подскажите пожалуйста как будет верно? Спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Но этот вариант не предусматривает момент, когда dom меняется после
>   загрузки.

Раз на то пошло, может вот так проще будет? т.е. без перебора и генерации замыканий и кучи функций

```
$('body').on('click', '.yourclass[data-test]', function (e) {
         var $this = $(this),
             dataTest = $this.attr('data-test');

            showTest(dataTest , $this);
            return false;
        });
```

> Не могу понять как переопределить контекст. На ум приходят методы bind и call

bind вполне верно использовать, для передач контекста, в вашем случае:

```
$(this).each(function (e) {
     var $this = $(this),
     dataTest = $this.attr('data-test');

     $this.on('click', function () {
        showTest(dataTest , this);
        return false;
    }.bind($this));
});
```

Comment: Помог первый вариант по [data-test]. Спасибо